# using by group processing First. and Last

Tags: sas

I just start learning sas and  would like some help with understanding the following chunk of code. The following program computes the annual payroll by department.

```
proc sort data = company.usa out=work.temp;
   by dept;
   run;
data company.budget(keep=dept payroll);
    set  work.temp;
    by dept;
    if wagecat ='S' then yearly = wagrate *12;
    else if wagecat = 'H' then yearly = wagerate *2000;
    if first.dept then payroll=0;
    payroll+yearly;
    if last.dept;

    run;
```

Questions:

1. What does out = work.temp do in the first line of this code?
2. I understand the data step created 2 temporary variables for each by variable (first.varibale/last.variable) and the values are either 1 or 0, but what does first.dept and last.dept exactly do here in the code?
3. Why do we need payroll=0 after first.dept in the second to the last line?

Comment: Run the data step, but store the last.dept and first.dept to specific variables so you can see how it operates. I would also add explicit output or PUT statements to see the processing - or use the DEBUG tool if you're feeling adventurous.

Comment: It's best to avoid asking multiple questions at the same time on Stack Overflow.  The first two questions can be answered by reading the SAS documentation.  The third question is a better one - it's calculating a summary, as Reeza explains below.

Answer (score 1):

This code takes the data for salaries and calculates the payroll amount for each department for a year, assuming salary is the same for all 12 months and that an hourly worker works 2000 hours.

1. It creates a copy of the data set which is sorted and stored in the work library. RTM.

[From the docs](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/proc/70377/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p02bhn81rn4u64n1b6l00ftdnxge.htm)

> OUT= SAS-data-set
>   names the output data set. If SAS-data-set does not exist, then PROC SORT creates it.
>   **CAUTION:**
>   **Use care when you use PROC SORT without OUT=.
>   Without the OUT= option, PROC SORT replaces the original data set with the sorted observations when the procedure executes without errors.
>   Default Without OUT=, PROC SORT overwrites the original data set.**
>   Tips    With in-database sorts, the output data set cannot refer to the input table on the DBMS.
>   You can use data set options with OUT=.
>   See SAS Data Set Options: Reference
>   Example Sorting by the Values of Multiple Variables

2. First.DEPT is an indicator variable that indicates the first observation of a specific BY group. So when you encounter the first record for a department it is identified. Last.DEPT is the last record for that specific department. It means the next record would the first record for a different department.
3. It sets PAYROLL to 0 at the first of each record. Since you have `if last.dept;` that means that only the last record for each department is outputted. This code is not intuitive - it's a manual way to sum the wages for people in each department. The common way would be to use a summary procedure, such as MEANS/SUMMARY but I assume they were trying to avoid having two passes of the data. Though if you're not sorting it may be just as fast anyways.

[Again, RTM here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/basess/68381/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n0t6f5rx0tvsvfn1t1r0ndy4n3e7.htm). The SAS documentation is quite thorough on these beginner topics.

Here's an alternative method that should generate the exact same results but is more intuitive IMO.

```
data temp;
  set company.usa;
  if wagecat='S' then factor=12; *salary in months;
  else if wagecat='H' then factor=2000; *salary in hours;
run;

proc means data=temp noprint NWAY;
class dept;
var wagerate;
weight factor;
output out=company.budget sum(wagerate)=payroll;
run;
```